# How do I format the geojson data so that it is accepted by Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, gis, mapbox-gl-js, h3

I have a geoJson of hex indexes, which I am trying to render on to mapbox.

Here is my code (ignore the indentation):

```
    export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const hexagons = ['8928308280fffff', '8928308281fffff', '8928308282fffff'];
    console.log(hex)
    this.state = {
      route:
      {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: hexagons.map(hex => ({
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Polygon',
            coordinates: h3ToGeoBoundary(hex, { resolution: 8 })
          }
        }))
    }, 
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapboxGL.MapView
          styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Light}
          zoomLevel={15}
          centerCoordinate={[11.256, 43.770]}
          style={styles.container}> 
          <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id='hexagons' shape={this.state.route}>
            <MapboxGL.FillExtrusionLayer id='hexagons' style={{ fillExtrusionColor: '#ff0000' }} />
          </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>

        </MapboxGL.MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is how the geojson looks when converting from hexagons[0]:

```
[[68.92995788193984, 31.831280499087402], [69.3935964899183, 62.345344956509784], [76.163042830191, 94.14309010184775], [87.36469532319619, 145.5581976913369], [81.27137179020501, -34.75841798028471], [73.31022368544396, 0.32561035194326043]]
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Mapbox error RCTMGLShapeSource.updateShape  The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. {"level": "error", "message": "RCTMGLShapeSource.updateShape  The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."}

Mapbox error Unable to read shape: {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[-122.41719971841654,37.77519778289337],...dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: \"Failed to decode GeoJSONSource `data` property\", underlyingError: nil)) setting it to empty"}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the H3 call here, but I don't actually think it's the problem. The function `h3ToGeoBoundary` takes a cell (which has a fixed resolution), and a boolean `formatAsGeoJSON` argument ([see docs](https://github.com/uber/h3-js/tree/v3.7.2#module_h3.h3ToGeoBoundary)). Your call `h3ToGeoBoundary(hex, { resolution: 8 })` is accidentally giving you GeoJSON, because  the `{ resolution: 8 }` argument is interpreted as truthy.

**But** that doesn't seem to be the issue here, as you get GeoJSON out anyway. I can't debug the issue here without a better error; a very strict GeoJSON parser might require a `properties` key in each `Feature`, but that seems unlikely. Note that you can also use the `geojson2h3` library to simplify the conversion from H3 to GeoJSON somewhat, though I can't guarantee that it will fix your problem in this case.

Comment: I have used the geojson2h3 - but no luck unfortunately. How would I go about debugging this? I have also removed the second param to h3toGeoBoundary, however it is still persistent with the same error..